# Override ArrayAdapter getView() int position

Tags: android

I'm trying create a custom array adapter for my listview, when it comes overriding the `getView` method, I'm not understanding the `int position` argument,
`public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)`, is it the index of the current view or is it the index of the array list that the arrayAdapter will fetch data from?

Below is the full code.

````
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> arrList){
        super(context,0, arrList);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listitemview = convertView;
        if(listitemview == null){
            listitemview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        }

        Word word = getItem(position);

        TextView defaultView =(TextView) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.english);
        defaultView.setText(word.getmDefaultTranslation());
        TextView miwokView =(TextView) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.miwok);
        miwokView.setText(word.getmMiwokTranslation());

        return listitemview;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getView()` is responsible to provide views to the listView so that it can display the listViewItems. The paremeter `int position` taken as an input by the `getView()` method is the index of the listView item. Now corresponding to the position of the listView item you want to add the relevant data to it. Suppose the 7th item is being displayed but you won't want the data from 3rd index in the arrayList to be displayed in the 7th item of the list view.

Say suppose getView method is being called for the 3rd index in the listView you can access the arrayList to get data from the 3rd index in the arrayList.

Conclusively the position parameter is the index of the current listView item and in the getView method you are using that position to get data from the arrayList in **THAT** position.

Comment: So what I'm getting is that when I add a view to the listview, that view will contain the index(lets say 5) that it got the data from the arrayList, and if I want to access the content of the added view again if it gets recycled, the getView() method can  provide the index 5 to fetch the data again from the arrayLIst. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Exactly everything here revolves around the index thing, say if you click on the 5th list item, then you can access other things that you have stored in the arrayList in the index 5. You have understood it absolutely correct!!

Comment: I once again read your question and I have edited my answer!!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not understanding the int position argument, public View
> getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup
> parent)

ArrayAdapter class has `getView()` method that is responsible for creating the views. So behind the scenes, a listview calls this method to get a view for a particular `position`. for more info [arrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)